# side_effect function of PropertyMock gets called only once

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest.mock

I have two questions regarding the mocking of a property with unittest.mock.PropertyMock (code will follow below):

1. Why does the test `test_prop` output "text_0, text_0" and not "text_0, text_1" as the test `test_func`? The output indicates, that the function `side_effect_func` in `test_prop` gets called only once, while I would have expected it to get called twice, like in `test_func`.
2. How can I specify a side_effect function for a property, that gets called every time the property is accessed?

My use case is that I would like to have a mock that returns a different name (which is a property) depending on how often it was called. This would "simulate" two different instances of Class1 to Class2 in the following minimal example.

**The code:**
File *dut.py*:

```
class Class1():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    def name_func(self):
        return self.__name


class Class2():
    def __init__(self, name, class1):
        self.__name = name
        self.__class1 = class1

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name
    @property
    def class1(self):
        return self.__class1
```

File *test\test_dut.py* (the second with-statement produces the exact same behavior when swapped with the first one):

```
import dut
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock

class TestClass2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_func(self):
        side_effect_counter = -1
        def side_effect_func(_):
            nonlocal side_effect_counter
            side_effect_counter += 1
            return f'text_{side_effect_counter}'

        c2_1 = dut.Class2('class2',  dut.Class1('class1'))
        c2_2 = dut.Class2('class2_2', dut.Class1('class1_2'))
        with patch('test_dut.dut.Class1.name_func', side_effect=side_effect_func, autospec=True):
            print(f'{c2_2.class1.name_func()}, {c2_1.class1.name_func()}')

    def test_prop(self):
        side_effect_counter = -1
        def side_effect_func():
            nonlocal side_effect_counter
            side_effect_counter += 1
            return f'text_{side_effect_counter}'

        c2_1 = dut.Class2('class2',  dut.Class1('class1'))
        c2_2 = dut.Class2('class2_2', dut.Class1('class1_2'))
        with patch.object(dut.Class1, 'name', new_callable=PropertyMock(side_effect=side_effect_func)):
        # with patch('test_dut.dut.Class1.name', new_callable=PropertyMock(side_effect=side_effect_func)):
            print(f'{c2_2.class1.name}, {c2_1.class1.name}')
```

Call from command line: `pytest -rP test\test_dut.py`
This leads to the following output (problematic line marked by me):

```
============================================================================================== test session starts ==============================================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.12, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\klosemic\Documents\playground_mocks
plugins: hypothesis-6.46.5, cov-3.0.0, forked-1.4.0, html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.1, xdist-2.5.0
collected 2 items

test\test_dut.py ..                                                                                                                                                                                        [100%]

==================================================================================================== PASSES =====================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ TestClass2.test_func ______________________________________________________________________________________________
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
text_0, text_1
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ TestClass2.test_prop ______________________________________________________________________________________________
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
text_0, text_0 <<<<<< HERE IS THE PROBLEM
=============================================================================================== 2 passed in 0.46s ===============================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has to do with *how* you are instantiating the `PropertyMock`. To answer your first question about why the second test prints `test_0` for both calls, you instantiate the `PropertyMock` class during your `with patch.object(get_events.Class1, 'name', new_callable=PropertyMock(side_effect=side_effect_func))` call.

Since you instantiate the class, it gets called *immediately* at the end of that line due to the logic of the `__enter__` method in the `patch` object. You can see that logic in [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L1481) line and then this [one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L1547). Due to that the value of your `side_effect` immediately becomes a string, which is essentially the output of the first call to the `PropertyMock`. This can be confirmed by changing your function to the following and observing the output:

```
with patch.object(dut.Class1, 'name', new_callable=PropertyMock(side_effect=side_effect_func)) as mock_prop:
    # print(f'{c2_2.class1.name}, {c2_1.class1.name}')
    print(mock_prop)
```

You will notice that this prints `text_0` in the console, confirming what has been mentioned above.

To answer your second question, the way to use `PropertyMock` in this case would be to change the second test to the following:

```
with patch.object(dut.Class1, 'name', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_prop:
    mock_prop.side_effect = side_effect_func
    print(f'{c2_2.class1.name}, {c2_1.class1.name}')
```

Then when you run the tests you get the correct output as shown below.

---

```
============================================================= test session starts =============================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***
plugins: asyncio-0.18.3, mock-3.7.0
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 2 items                                                                                                                             

tests/test_dut.py ..                                                                                                                 [100%]

=================================================================== PASSES ====================================================================
____________________________________________________________ TestClass2.test_func _____________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------
text_0, text_1
____________________________________________________________ TestClass2.test_prop _____________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------
text_0, text_1
============================================================== 2 passed in 0.01s ==============================================================
```

Comment: In this configuration, could the side_effect_func have a reference to the self object ? For example, instead of having the call counts, one could inspect the self object and and return something from side_effect_func according to that.